# Sending text onto network using OSC/UDP

Tags: java, android, udp, packet, osc

I am trying to send out packets with text that corresponds with a button press, then capture it on wireshark. I am using OSC/UDP and, while the code seems correct, I am failing to see any packets sent from my phone.

For now, I am only using OSCPortOut:

```
    OSCPortOut reciever ;
    OSCListener listener ;
    OSCPortOut sender ;
    String sendIPaddr;
    int sendPort;
```

Then, OnCreate, I am connecting to the designated IP (my PC).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //   setContentView(R.layout.playerlogin);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Size = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.size);
        Speed =(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.speed);
        Agility=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.agility);
        Vision =(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.vision);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Size.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        Speed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        Agility.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        Vision.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        try {
       InetAddress otherIP = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2");

       sender = new OSCPortOut(otherIP,5000);
   }catch (Exception e){
       text.setText("IO Exc: "
               + e.getClass().getName() + ", "
               + e.getMessage());
   }
    }
```

On radio button click, I am trying to send the text corresponding with the click out on to the network.

```
 public void onRadioClick(View v) {

        n = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.north);
        s = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.south);
        e = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.east);
        w = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.west);
        c = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.center);
        //String direction = text.setText();
        // or, you can check each radiobutton and find which one is checked.
        if (n.isChecked()) {
            text.setText("North");
        } else if (s.isChecked()) {
            text.setText("South");
        } else if (e.isChecked()) {
            text.setText("East");
        } else if (w.isChecked()) {
            text.setText("West");
        } else if (c.isChecked()) {
            text.setText("Center");
        }
        String direction = String.valueOf(text);
        try{
            sender.send(new OSCMessage(direction));
        }catch(Exception E){
}
```

Initially, there was an issue accessing the port, but this was resolved by adding a permission to the manifest. Does anyone have any ide why I am not seeing North, South, East West or Center in any of the UDP packets that I am capturing?

Comment: Does your phone has an IP in 192.168.1.x subnet?

Comment: Yes, it does. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

In the MainCativity, this  must be added for any network communication:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```